# simple regex assistance removing brackets and contents inbetween

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove the brackets and everything in-between:

```
$url = 'abc[wenn]';
echo preg_replace('/\[(.)\]/i','',$url);
```

What's incorrect about my regular expression?

Comment: Is there a possibility that the brackets are nested ?

Comment: You might have a simple string manipulation option here that could perform better than regex depending on how the expected values for the string you are evaluating.  Will there always be exactly one set of brackets? Will the bracketed section always be at the end of the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the star `*` or `+` quantifier for this to work:

```
/\[.*?\]/i
```

Without it the `(.)` will only match a single character.

Even better, if the value between `[` and `]` can't contain `]` itself then you can use a more powerful expression:

```
/\[[^\]]+\]
```

Comment: @hek2mgl What is it useless ?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Didn't looked carefully.. It's ok and an alternative +1

Comment: +1 Can be written as `/\[[^]]*]/` (be careful with the quantifier and the OP request)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thank you, I know but I didn't want confusion the regular expression as it already seems confusing because all of the `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 2):

You have no **quantifier** set in place, therefore the match fails and the string is being repeated. You are also using the `i` modifier (case-insensitive) which is useless in this case and can be removed.

The following quantifiers are recognized.

```
*      Match 0 or more times
+      Match 1 or more times
```

The following would be the approach you are looking for.

```
preg_replace('/\[[^\]]*\]/', '', $url);
```

Regular expression:

```
\[             '['
 [^\]]*        any character except: '\]' (0 or more times)
\]             ']'
```

If you have nested brackets you want removed, `abc[foo[bar[baz]]]` you could use the following:

```
preg_replace('/\[(?:[^\[\]]|(?R))*\]/', '', $url);
```